# Force Close Apps When Run, With LogCat Fatal Exception Error Inflating Class RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Create an App using `RecyclerView` and `Retrofit` to Call Data from an API.

There's no error message in the java and XML file.  But when I run the apps. It's force close.

with this message on its Log Cat.

> 08-07 16:45:13.735 18311-18311/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   08-07 16:45:13.739 18311-18311/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: eldarcreative.myapplication, PID: 18311
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eldarcreative.myapplication/eldarcreative.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecycvlerView
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2525)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2617)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:218)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5657)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:990)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecycvlerView
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                                                          at eldarcreative.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6135)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2617) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:218) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5657) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:990) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.RecycvlerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/eldarcreative.myapplication-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/eldarcreative.myapplication-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/eldarcreative.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/eldarcreative.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/eldarcreative.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/eldarcreative.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/eldarcreative.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/eldarcreative.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/eldarcreative.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/eldarcreative.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/eldarcreative.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/eldarcreative.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                          at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                                                          at eldarcreative.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32) 
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6135) 
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2617) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:218) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5657) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:990) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                       Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.RecycvlerView
>                                                          at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                                                          at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                               ... 23 more
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

Main Acitvity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CustomAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView mrecyclerview;
    List<Result> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mrecyclerview= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(resultList);
        mrecyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
        mrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this,2));
        new RequestMovie().execute("popular");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       if (item.getItemId()== R.id.action_popular){
           new RequestMovie().execute("popular");
       } else if (item.getItemId()==R.id.action_top_rated){
           new RequestMovie().execute("top_rated");
       }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class RequestMovie extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            String kategori = params[0];
            if (kategori.equals("popular")){
                ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getRetrofit()
                        .create(ApiInterface.class);
                Call <EldarMovie> call = apiInterface.getPopular();
                call.enqueue(new Callback<EldarMovie>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<EldarMovie> call, Response<EldarMovie> response) {
                        EldarMovie movie=response.body();
                        adapter.setData(movie.getResults());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<EldarMovie> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });


            } 
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Main Activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="eldarcreative.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecycvlerView

        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecycvlerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I read some other case which already posted here, but I still didn't find any clue how to fix my case.

Any idea?

Comment: You need to show us the code.In the `Logcat`,I saw `ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.RecycvlerView`.So you can check it.

Comment: what its mean...?

Comment: You problem is `ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.RecycvlerView`.You can find it and solve it by yourself.Also,you can show us the code and I will find it and solve it.

Comment: already edit .. i add my main activity.Java,

Comment: Could you show me the `activity_main.xml` ?

Comment: added, sorry for late reply, lag because i'm rebuild my project

Comment: change `RecycvlerView` to `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `android.support.v7.widget.RecycvlerView` with `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`